# How to identify changes to an email address in Active Directory

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, ldap-query, active-directory-group

Is there way to identify changes that happened to an email address in `Active Directory`?

```
(&(objectClass=user)(whenCreated>=20141022083730.0Z))
```

The above search query gives the changes that happen to a user. By the same way I would like to find the following things that change in `Active Directory`

- Adding of a new email address group or user
- Deletion of an email address
- Adding of an email alias

Comment: Audit logging. Object creation logging for new objects. proxyAddresses field for deletion and addition. There's no attribute you can use to find this kind of thing out. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc731607(v=ws.10).aspx. Beyond that, the question is in the wrong place, it's not a coding problem.

Comment: What @ChrisDent said. This question is more suitable for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), though.